# Can you login an admin user on the front end at the same time, automatically?

Tags: magento-1.9, login

I would like to be able to login admin users to their corresponding frontend accounts when they log in to admin. This is so that internal orders can be placed with people correctly logged in.

I have managed to get the admin login event observer working and from there I have tried to set the default store to the frontend store, then tried to create a frontend session, looking up the frontend user by email, the email address retrieved from the admin user object. I can load customer by email to get an id and nothing complains when I try and make the frontend session.

If I then try and browse the frontend in a different tab I would expect to be 'logged in' but this is not the case.

Does anyone have any ideas on how to do this?

Comment: Tag with your version

Comment: could you add the Version of Magento and any relevant code please,  you could also take a look at the loginPost controller for a bit of help on the frontend side of things